# Hilt + view model dont build

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class WControlViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val getProfile: GetProfile,
private val getHistory: GetHistory,
) : ViewModel() {...}
```

Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
private val vModel: WControlViewModel by viewModels()
```

Application

```
@HiltAndroidApp
```

class WControlApp :Application()

But project not build, error :

```
 return DefaultViewModelFactories.getActivityFactory(this);
                                ^
required: ComponentActivity,Factory
found: Hilt_MainActivity
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Can you please share your app level `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Can you share your AppModule Di

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, which I resolved by ensuring the hilt plugin version was upgraded.  In my case I went from 2.33-beta to 2.35.1

So in the dependency in your project’s root build.gradle file

```
    classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1"
```

You can find the latest version numbers here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android-gradle-plugin

Comment: Even after updating to the latest version, I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same issue so, I changed my project level dependency and app level dependency.

Try this

in App Level Gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35.1"
```

in Project Level Gradle:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1"
```

Happy Coding!!